# setlocale() function returning false

Tags: php, gettext

So, I have been trying to translate a website to Spanish on windows 10 using gettext in PHP. Below is the setlocale.php file. A form makes post request to setlocale.php which sends required locale (that are en_US or es_ES), I found that setlocale returns **English_United States.1252**, when passing en_US in the parameters, and returns **false** for es_ES is passed in the parameters.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $lang = $_POST['language'];
    $_SESSION['LANG'] = $lang;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['LANG']) && !is_null($_SESSION['LANG'])) {
    $language = $_SESSION['LANG'];
} else {
    $language = "en_US";
}

$result = setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

$domain = "messages";
$dir = __DIR__ . "/locale";
bindtextdomain($domain, $dir);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    header("Location:" . $_POST['pageRef']);
}
```

[image: below is the directory structure for setlocale.php]

Below is the catalog property of the .po file (I am using Poedit here.):

[image: catalog properties for messages.po file]

Comment: PHP's locales are using the underlying OS, so make sure that locale is installed in the OS.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this solution was already given in previous gettext questions for only Linux, I looked up for the windows, but can't find anything. Do you have any idea how to check in Windows?

Comment: AFAIR, on Windows you have to call `setlocale()` with something like `Spanish` or `Span ish_Spain`, or `Spanish_Mexico`. Does that work? I had done that in Perl years ago: https://github.com/gflohr/libintl-perl/blob/master/lib/Locale/Util.pm (search for `sub __set_locale_windows`). Short answer: You probably have to write a mapping of locale codes or send codes that Windows accepts, not the glibc style locale identifiers.

Comment: Actually, you should always map the locale identifiers. For the web, browsers send codes like 'en-us', whereas `setlocale()` on Unix systems expects codes like `en_US`. So it's not only Windows that requires a mapping.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr comment was really helpful, I just chnaged the code. Now, I am not getting false, but the pages are still not getting translated. I also tried chnaging the directory name from es_ES to Spanish_Spain:1252 (that's wahat I am getting from setlocale()). But It is still not working. I have also included the catalog properties of the message.po file in the question. Is there anything wrong with the properties?

Comment: Can you start by changing your code and hardcoding `$language` to `"Spanish_Spain"`? I think that you have to strip off the codepage and the colon.

Comment: Do you have gimp installed on your windows box? Or any other program that is localized with gettext. You can check the directory structure of the installed locale directory. Does it use `Spanish_Spain` or `es_ES`? I have no windows machine and cannot check myself. Edit: But I have the gettext source code. It seems to normalize the locale identifiers to the Unix form. So you should rename the directory to `es_ES`.

Comment: You may also experiment with setting the (undocumented) environment variable `GETTEXT_MUI` to a truthy value.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr I have tried changing directory name with (es_ES, es-ES, Spanish_Spain, Spanish_Spain) and none of them works. I also hardcoded the value, but it produced no result. You are telling me about GETTEXT_MUI. I don't know about this. Can you give me link to an article where I can read about this.

Comment: I found `GETTEXT_MUI` in the source code of gettext. It's marked as experimental there.